# How to stop the extra language folders in my asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, multilingual

Does anyone know how to stop the language specific folders from being built in the bin directory of my Asp.Net projects?

I have built a number of different intranet apps that will never need to be multilingual and the systems admins are questioning the presence of folders that are not needed.

I can manually delete but I would rather not have them deployed in the first place.

bin-
 de
 es
 fr
 it
 ja
 ko
 ru
 zh-Hans
 zh-Hant

Comment: Could you put a directory tree so we know what folders you're talking about? Some of them are system and can't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the language specific folders add by some package, that included in asp.net project template by default. You can open package manager is VS and analyse which package addes language folders, and remove it.

If you don't want to see this folders, you should create empty project.